# What is the current UPS shipping gateway? (outage 2019-01-06)

Tags: shipping-methods, ups

I'm using Magento 1.7, and it uses the UPS shipping calculator at

http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi

Since yesterday afternoon, it has been returning a `404 not found` and this is preventing anyone from placing an order!   I'm very surprised that the entire Magento community isn't on fire with this event... so maybe I just have an old URL that nobody is using anymore?  Does anyone know if this service has been retired or if it is a temporary outage?

Comment: Thanks for posting the fix. A shame UPS didn't notify about the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144815)

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this!!! Saved us a lot of time and effort. I called ups and of course they had no clue only mentioning api developer kits. They should say something somewhere about this. Best,
Joe

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144826)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply need to update the UPS Gateway URL to use "https"

To change this setting, login to the backend of your Magento website and then go to :

1. System > Configuration
2. Click “Shipping Methods”
3. Click the tab for “UPS”
4. Find the “Gateway URL” setting and change the url from “http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi” to “https://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi”.

I put together a quick video on how to fix it here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNHQb3X7Lys&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out, the shipping gateway now requires https instead of http.

https://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi

Though, it is disturbing that I can't find any documentation about this API on UPS's website.