# UPS stopped working from yesterday in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, api, shipping, ups

I was using **UPS** in my Magento 2 store, from today I found that the shipping methods are not fetched and they are displayed with the message

```
Unfortunately we cannot provide a shipping quote at this time
```

I tried to enable **debug log** for UPS and no log was found. The same issue does occur in the dev site too from today. Please find the configurations

[image]
[image]
[image]

So I tried UPS in another live store where **UPS type** was `UPS XML`, it was displaying shipping rates fine. I switched type to `UPS` and the shipping rates weren't fetched. I checked it in **fresh Magento** too. Does anyone have an idea about this? Else anyone facing the same problem? Whether might it be an issue with UPS API service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Gateway Url of UPS from http to https
From “http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi” to “https://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi”.

Refer this link 
[What is the current UPS shipping gateway? (outage 2019-01-06)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257013/what-is-the-current-ups-shipping-gateway-outage-2019-01-06)

Comment: Thank you. That is working fine. But I am don't know how the gateway was working fine for almost 2 months after the change

Comment: Actually, i ran into the problem in January and *again* early last week.  I had changed my config but it turned out that the old value got pulled in from the cache somehow.  So, I assume UPS reverted their https requirement at some point, then re-applied it last week, else my site would have been broken again before last week.